# Who defined the term "end-to-end encryption"?

Tags: encryption, terminology

I am trying to find the origin of the term "end-to-end encryption", but have been unsuccessful until now.

Comment: I'm seeing references to the term in 1977 at MIT

Comment: Perhaps it is simply a natural term to describe and differentiate.

Comment: It's a natural term nowdays, but it seems that the "end-to-end argument"(and by argument it can be encryption, bit error recovery, duplicated message suppression) was created by Jerome H. Saltzer(http://web.mit.edu/Saltzer/) from MIT as @schroeder said. In a broad way he wanted to define end-to-end argument as a key organizing principle of the Internet. Take a read at this doc written by him - http://web.mit.edu/Saltzer/www/publications/endtoend/endtoend.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first reference that I found was from Paul Baran of Rand in 1964, in the manual [On Distributed Communications](http://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2006/RM3765.pdf). The link is to Chapter 9, which deals with security. Naturally, as this is from before the time of WhatsApp, Skype, Tor, etc., it does not deal with many of the threat models or use cases for E2E encryption that we see now.

This manual is further [cited by](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=15162817362992998292&as_sdt=5,39&sciodt=0,39&hl=en) Saltzer, Diffie-Hellman...